# ios Tab Bar Navigation

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am wondering if it is possible to have a view controller in an iOS app that has a tabbar @ the bottom with links to other view controllers but no tab for the current view itself?

Ideally what I would like to do is have a view controller A with a tab bar to views B and C. When navigating to page B or C you would see the B/C tab selected in the tab bar. When navigating back to controller A you would not see the tab bar, but once navigating back to view B/C it would show again.

Not that should matter but I am using Xamarin for development.

Comment: Why down vote without an answer/comment?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to. You add a UITabBar to ViewA. You can then add ViewB and ViewC as UITabBarItems to the UITabBar.

You would need a button in ViewB and ViewC that leads back to View A to get back to it (since ViewA will not be listed in the tab bar).

You can NOT use a UITabBarController for this. UITabBarController does not allow for customizing the UITabBar like this.

Comment: Ahh ok this makes sense. I was having difficulty trying to manipulate the UITabBarController tab items. 

However when adding a tab bar in the design I notice that there are not pins on it to pin it to the sides (and fix it @ the bottom). Doesnt look like there is an easy way to have a smiple page with for example a table view taking up the whole page except for the tab bar @ the bottom. This would be doable adding the bar progrmatically and sizing the controls based off the view bonds but do not see a simple way to do it in the designer

Comment: That's weird. I was able to get the pins for a Tab Bar in Xamarin Studio. When you first drop it in, it has the circles on either side, but after you click it again it should give you the constraint pins. Then you can constrain it to the bottom and sides (and adjust width to match parent), and constrain the Table View above it to the top of the Tab Bar.

Sometimes Xamarin is weird about giving those constraint pins. I would try deleting it and adding it again..

Comment: Hmm, I am using Visual Studio. I wonder if there is a bug for this